# How to generate a breadcrumb structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I got Page objects that are linked together with a page_id attribute.
I am looking for a way to print out a complete breadcrumb structure from a select Page object.

*I tried this code but it does only show first level:*

```
def self.breadcrumbs page_id
    page = Page.find page_id
    return page unless page.page_id
    breadcrumbs page.page_id
  end
```

*So if I got three Page objects and the object ID I am using is 2:*

```
Page A
id: 1
page_id: 0
title: "Page A"

Page B
id: 2
page_id: 1
title: "Page B"

Page C
id: 3
page_id: 2
title: "Page C"
```

*The output I am looking for is:*

```
Page A > Page B > Page C
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the function you wrote is recursive -- it doesn't build anything, it will always return the root of the breadcrumbs.

This should build the hierarchy out to the selected page...

```
def self.breadcrumbs(page_id)
  page_breadcrumbs = []
  current_page = Page.find page_id
  
  parent_page = Page.find_by(id: current_page.page_id)
  if parent_page.present?
    page_breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs(parent_page.id)
  end
  page_breadcrumbs << current_page
  return page_breadcrumbs

end
```

Then to display, something like this...

```
@breadcrumbs = Page.breadcrumbs(2)

<% @breadcrumbs.each_with_index do |breadcrumb, idx| %>
  <% if idx < @breadcrumbs.length %>
    <%= link_to breadcrumb.title, page_path(breadcrumb.id) %> >
  <% else %>
    <%= breadcrumb.title %>
  <% end 
<% end %>
```

BTW, I think part of the problem is `page_id` is confusing, I would use `parent_page_id` to make it clear you intend a hierarchy.